# Why is this regex not matched in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need to find "`7.1/10`" in "`7.1/10&nb`" with the following regex:

```
\d{1}\.?\d{0,2}\/10
```

But the following code does not match anything:

```
rating= "7.1/10&nb"
p = re.compile(re.escape("\d{1}\.?\d{0,2}\/10"))
m = p.match(rating)
if m:
    print("rating: {}".format(m.group()))
else:
    print("no match found in {}".format(rating))
```

What's the problem with my code?

Comment: you need to use raw string literal `r` instead of `re.escape` `p = re.compile(r"\d{1}\.?\d{0,2}\/10")`

Comment: Change `p = re.compile(re.escape("\d{1}\.?\d{0,2}\/10"))` to `p = re.compile(r"\d{1}\.?\d{0,2}\/10")` it will work.

Comment: also, i suspect that you _may_ have problem later while using `match`..because `match` matches only in starting of string..

Comment: @rock321987 Please post your answer

Comment: well someone already posted..no need to add redundancy

Comment: @Meysam rock means you should use other re methods rather than `match` if you want to find all the results

Comment: @J.Joe Thank you for the point. But I only need the first match.

Comment: no its not the first match you find by `match`..if you have `ab 7.1/10` you wont be able to find anything using `match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change only one line in your code.

`p = re.compile(re.escape("\d{1}\.?\d{0,2}\/10"))` **to** `re.compile(r"\d{1}\.?\d{0,2}\/10")`

It will work smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

`p = re.compile(r"\d\.?\d{0,2}/10")`

There are several problems in you re:

- add 'r' for raw string or you will have to escape all '\':
  `re.compile("\\d\\.?\\d{0,2}/10")`
- \d{1} can be \d
- `\/` can be /, no need to escape